# How to set location in redirect /cas/login callback in spring security

Tags: spring-security, cas

Spring CAS will redirect back to the url which is forbidden,
as frontend send rest api as ajax request, so Spring Security default redirect doesn't work

I have to send SSO url `cas_login_url/service=?my_service_cas_login` in response.
and frontend will do `window.location.href = cas_login_url/service=?my_service_cas_login` to jump to the SSO login page.

it will redirect to `"/"` as I can see the location is `"/"` in the spring cas validate api which is ******/cas/login?ticket=TS*************

If I want to make the location as customize url, what should I do, where should I pass the param?

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but in case someone is still wondering: your need to configure your **CasAuthenticationFilter** with an AuthenticationSuccessHandler (like any authentication filter).

For instance if you just want to redirect to the url "/welcome":

```
filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/welcome"));
```

you can add a spring bean to any class file annotated w/ @Configuration:

```
@Bean
public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, ServiceProperties casServiceProperties) throws Exception {
        CasAuthenticationFilter filter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login/cas");
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        filter.setServiceProperties(casServiceProperties);
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/welcome"));
        return filter;
    }
```

Although if going this route, you should not hard-code the value "/welcome" in the code, you could use a value in application.properties